# Change excel colors with only text? No user input?

Tags: excel

Basically I have a button on a webpage that outputs data to a .csv or .xls sheet.  Is there any way for me to specify the color(either the background or text color) without any further user input.  Is there a way for me to specify a conditional format formula, and have excel load it, without the user doing anything other than opening the document?

Thanks

Comment: Not for CSV, since it's a "data only" format. For xls it depends on how you're creating the xls output, so you will need to add more details.

Comment: if you're loading an excel file can't you save the conditional formatting into a template and have the data load into that template?

Comment: Would that template not need to be on each users computer first?  I was hoping to have something that would popup on each users computer without any other effort.  Without color it works great... adding color seems to be a bit of a roadblock, at least in terms of universal one-click access

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a Conditional not based on values; use this option :
`Use a formula to determine wich cells to format`

[image]

> Note: In `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager` windows -which opens by selecting `Manage Rules` item- select **`This Worksheet`**.

Now Enter your formula like these:

```
= AND(ROW() = 1; COLUMN() = 5)   --=> Cell(E1)
= (ROW() = 5)                    --=> Row(5)
= (COLUMN() = 2)                 --=> COLUMN(B)
```

> Note : If two of `"` comes at first and at end of your formula => remove them.